# RSA encoding with $26$ letters

Tags: linear-algebra

We substitute the $26$ letters of the alphabet by the numbers $0, 1, . . . , 25$ (so $A =
0, B = 1, C = 2, . . . , Z = 25$). The public key encoding function is $$ x → x^{43}  \pmod {85}$$ (With this we can encode the numbers $0, 1, . . . , 84$ but only the first $26$
numbers have meaning.)

What is the original message if the one encoded by this
function is $59, 45, 7, 52, 45, 75$?

I know I can do it with RSA encoding however I don't know how I can find $d$

Comment: yes it is . I dont know how to write it

Comment: it is problem from our exercise set

Comment: It seems that $A=1$, $B=2$, $\ldots$ is meant.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I think $A\mapsto 2, B\mapsto 3,\ldots$ would actually be more appropriate, considering that neither $0$ nor $1$ are encrypted. Maybe even skip all multiples of $5$ and $17$. But cryptographic security is not really part of the problem here.

Comment: @Arthur: When $A=0$ the deciphering does not give something interesting, but when $A=1$ we obtain an English word.

Comment: anyone has proper solution?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I wasn't commenting on whether that encoding was correct for this particular problem. But rather whether it was correct if you want to use this for a decent hand-encryption scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can just do brute force.  Pick a value for $x$, like $3$.  Compute, say by Alpha, $3^{43}\equiv 7 \pmod {85}$.  Then in a spreadsheet compute the powers of $7 \bmod 85$ and note that $7^3 \equiv 3 \pmod{85}$.  That is your decrypting exponent.  So $59^3 \equiv 19 \pmod {85}$ and the first character is $19$, which in the $A=0$ case gives $T$.  As Christian Blattner says, if you use the $A=1$ encoding you get an appropriate word, but the problem calls for $A=0$.

The usual approach is to compute $d$ from $de\equiv 1 \pmod {\phi(85)}.$  As $\phi(85)=64$ you are looking for a multiple of $43$ that is one more than a multiple of $64$.  We have $3 \cdot 43 \equiv 1 \pmod {64}$